# bug Button Ripple Effect on Click

Tags: javascript, html

I follow a video for make a Button Ripple Effect on Click, but it didn't work... The animation must be in the button "plus d'information", but it's not. I don't understand why it doesn't work...! [I followed this tutorial]. You can see, the bubble effect isn't on the  balise but in the page... I don't understand why

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 100vh;
    background: #202735;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
img{
    width: 125px;
}
.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.container .card{
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    background: #E7ECEF;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 30px 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.container .card .imgbox{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.container .card:hover .imgbox{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    left: -75px;
    top: calc(50% - 75px);
}
.container .card .imgbox img{
    max-width: 100px;
    transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.container .card:hover .imgbox img{
    max-width: 75px;
    filter: invert(1);
}
.container .card .content{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.container .card .content h1{
    color: #db5a42;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.container .card .content a{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #4790FD;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border: #4790FD solid 2px;
}
span{
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    pointer-events: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: animate 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animate{
    0%{
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    100%{
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
/* https://coolors.co/202735-4790fd-e7ecef-817f75-23967f
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="imgbox">
                <img src="./img/portfolio/logo_blanc.png">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div>
                    <h1>Silvus Site</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                        Etiam sed laoreet mauris. Sed vitae ligula quam. Nunc non interdum nunc, nec dapibus nunc.</p>
                    <a href="#">Plus D'information</a>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('a');
        buttons.forEach(btn => {
            btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

            let x = e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft;
            let y = e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop; 

            let ripples = document.createElement('span');
            ripples.style.left = x + 'px';
            ripples.style.top = y + 'px';
            this.appendChild(ripples);

            setTimeout(() => {
                ripples.remove()
            }, 1000);
            })
        })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify the problem: what is the intended behavior and what have you attempted

Comment: I would like to do a white wave effect when I click on my <a> tag but the problem is that I followed the tutorial that I linked to my question but the wave effect goes anywhere on my page and not in my <a> button. I hardly know about js so I just have to follow the tutorial